# Remove a substring from String

Tags: c#, string, substring

Is there a way to remove substrings from my string on the basis of any identifier?

For example, I have:

```
string codeID = "347439>Dome";
```

I want to have only that part of string that occurs before `>`

The result should look like this:

```
string newCodeId = "347439"
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Maybe look at the documentation for the IndexOf & Substring methods

Comment: Yes, split and get the first item, or get a substring up to the first occurrence of `>` (use `IndexOf(">")`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this could be another possibility:

```
string codeID = "347439>Dome";

string newCodeId = codeID.Split('>')[0];

Console.WriteLine(newCodeId);
```

It uses the [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) method which returns a `string[]`. To get the left part of the `string` here I took the first element in the array. The rest of the string is (in this case) in position `1`.

in the case that there is not `>` separator in the string. It will return just the entire old string in position `[0]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Split()` method:

```
string codeID = "347439>Dome";
string result = codeID.Split('>')[0];
```

Comment: 20 seconds faster! ;) chapó

Answer (score 1):

You could use also System.Linq:

```
string result = codeID.Split('>').First();
```

Answer (score 0):

this should replace everything after your '>'

```
var newCodeId = Regex.Replace(codeID , "[>].*", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Using a regex to solve this is like using a sledge hammer to open a walnut

Comment: He didn't specify how he wanted to do it.   I understand not everyone appreciates regular expressions, in instances like this I find it simpler.

Comment: It's more the ineffciency. The RegEx engine isn't particularly efficent in C#. This will have a significant overhead when compared to `Substring()`. Like not an massive issue in this scenario but personally I will typically only use a regex as a last resort becuse of this.

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with Fubo's answer but you can also **split** the string using [string.split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) function. and can take the first index value.

```
string codeID = "347439>Dome";
string result = codeID.Split('>')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Method : SubString()

```
string codeID = "347439>Dome";
char splitChar = '>';
if (codeID.Contains(splitChar))
{
 int charIndex = codeID.IndexOf(splitChar);
 string subString = codeID.Substring(0,charIndex);
}
```